# Find the highest order bit in C

Tags: c

what I'm after is something I can feed a number into and it will return the highest order bit.  I'm sure there's a simple way.  Below is an example output (left is the input)

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 2
4 -> 4
5 -> 4
6 -> 4
7 -> 4
8 -> 8
9 -> 8
...
63 -> 32
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
int hob (int num)
{
    if (!num)
        return 0;

    int ret = 1;

    while (num >>= 1)
        ret <<= 1;

    return ret;
}
```

hob(1234) returns 1024
hob(1024) returns 1024
hob(1023) returns 512

Comment: To make it work with zeros just add:
while (num >>= 1 && num)

Comment: Actually you need an if to check for zero. Since ret starts at 1 and grows, this algorithm won't make it hit 0, the answer for the input of 0.

Comment: My answer is better. No loops!

Comment: a good compiler will unroll loops for performance. If it actually does perform faster w/o the loop.

Comment: For GCC, the better function is __builtin_clz(v) -- it returns the number of leading (binary) zeros, and hence you can get the most significant bit position by 32-clz(num) (or 64-clzll(num) for 64 bit)

Answer (score 93):

From Hacker's Delight:

```
int hibit(unsigned int n) {
    n |= (n >>  1);
    n |= (n >>  2);
    n |= (n >>  4);
    n |= (n >>  8);
    n |= (n >> 16);
    return n - (n >> 1);
}
```

This version is for 32-bit ints, but the logic can be extended for 64-bits or higher.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be a bit more efficient to use XOR in the last line?
n ^ (n >> 1)

Comment: @alveko while XOR can be implemented faster than subtraction at the transistor/gate level, they will take the same number of clock cycles on most modern CPUs

Comment: less transistors, more efficiency, less heat, more cycles :)

Comment: For intuition, this "spreads" the MSB to the right, so that 0b100010 becomes 0b111111, then shifts right for 0b011111 and subtracts that, yielding 0b100000.

Comment: Could any one tell me what the theory behind it?

Comment: But this will not work for the case, where all bit of the numbers are set. It incorrectly returns 0. Consider 0x80000000 for a 32 bit number.

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta In that case, wouldn’t it return 0xFFFFFFFF - 0x7FFFFFFF = 0x80000000? Please explain where you see an error.

Comment: Oh please pardon me, You are right. I was using the parameter n as signed int. In case of unsigned int, Your code works fine.

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta Okay, I see. It's a little unclear how to define "highest order bit" for negative numbers. Would it be the "sign bit", since it will always be set for negative numbers? The highest order bit of the absolute value? This function handles unsigned types, where the meaning is unambiguous.

Comment: IMO, it should be signed bit for all the negative numbers.

Answer (score 42):

`fls` bottoms out to a hardware instruction on many architectures. I suspect this is probably the simplest, fastest way of doing it.

```
1<<(fls(input)-1)
```

Comment: Clearly the best answer. I wonder why all those websites like bit twiddling hacks, who focus so much on reducing the number of operations for this kind of problems, don't even mention this.

Comment: What happens if a bit is not set? How does one shift left by a negative count? I believe that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @jww That is correct. `fls(0)` -> 0, leaving the rhs of `<<` negative, which is undefined. In my defense, this was not stated in the problem space ;-)

Comment: @Fabian - OK, plus one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I'm glad I kept scrolling!

Comment: @krs013 - I don't know. It isn't available outside of POSIX if not mistaken.

Comment: Is ``fls`` the same as ``ffs``? I test the answer in my environment using ``ffs`` and the result seems not right for case like ``input = 5``.

Comment: ffs (find first significant) is the opposite of fls (find last significant)

(fls finds most significant bit, ffs finds the least significant bit).

Comment: `_BitScanReverse()` reportedly the same thing for microsoft, so could be used in place of `fls()` eg, by a conditionalt #define

Comment: I don't know why I can't use the `fls()` function. I tried to `#include <strings.h>` as the manual says but still don't find it... Is it deprecated? I don't know.

Comment: [`fls` isn't defined by POSIX, though `ffs` is.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  glibc hasn't got it either.  FreeBSD does, but OpenBSD doesn't.

Answer (score 27):

like obfuscated code? Try this:

1 << ( int) log2( x)

Comment: I love this solution, but it's just a little too obfuscated.  Still gets a vote as the most compact solution.

Comment: If you want to pawn the job off on the FPU, sure. :)

Comment: Mathematically correct, but this could be much slower than bitwise operations.

Comment: But x86 FPUs are plenty fast these days.

Comment: It is possible to find `log2` using bitwise, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12376351/111307)

Comment: If you cast it to double first, the exponent part of the number readily tells you the order.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution to this same problem and this makes my brain hurt.

Comment: If you want speed and know what the value would be at compile time, use `boost::static_log2`

Comment: Be careful with the number representations. This recipe works fine for positive 32 bit integers. But `std::log2()` returns `nan` for negative arguments and `int(nan)` evaluates to `0x80000000` which is the largest negative int. This can be observed for g++7.3 but I am afraid that this is not portable. Next issue is with roundoff-errors. When you feed 64 bit numbers, everything works fine up to 2^{48}-1. But for 2^{49}-1 the recipe returns 2^{49}.

Answer (score 9):

Little bit late to this party but the simplest solution I found, given a modern GCC as a compiler is simply:

```
static inline int_t get_msb32 (register unsigned int val)
{
  return 32 - __builtin_clz(val);
}

static inline int get_msb64 (register unsigned long long val)
{
  return 64 - __builtin_clzll(val);
}
```

It's even relatively portable (at the very least it will work on any GCC platform).

Comment: Also supported by clang.

Answer (score 7):

Continually remove the low order bit comes to mind...

```
int highest_order_bit( int x )
{
    int y = x;
    do { 
        x = y;
        y = x & (x-1); //remove low order bit
    }
    while( y != 0 );
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The linux kernel has a number of handy bitops like this, coded in the most efficient way for a number of architectures.  You can find generic versions in [include/asm-generic/bitops/fls.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.26.5/include/asm-generic/bitops/fls.h) (and friends), but see also [include/asm-x86/bitops.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.26.5/include/asm-x86/bitops.h) for a definition using inline assembly if speed is of the essence, and portability is not.

Comment: The Linux kernel is full of undefined behavior in bitops. I don't recommend anyone use it (or copy/paste the routines) unless they know what they are doing or have a complete set of self tests for the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

A fast way to do this is via a look-up table. For a 32-bit input, and an 8-bit look-up table, in only requires 4 iterations:

```
int highest_order_bit(int x)
{
    static const int msb_lut[256] =
        {
            0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, // 0000_0000 - 0000_0111
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, // 0000_1000 - 0000_1111
            4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, // 0001_0000 - 0001_0111
            4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, // 0001_1000 - 0001_1111
            5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, // 0010_0000 - 0010_0111
            5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, // 0010_1000 - 0010_1111
            5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, // 0011_0000 - 0011_0111
            5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, // 0011_1000 - 0011_1111

            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0100_0000 - 0100_0111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0100_1000 - 0100_1111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0101_0000 - 0101_0111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0101_1000 - 0101_1111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0110_0000 - 0110_0111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0110_1000 - 0110_1111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0111_0000 - 0111_0111
            6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, // 0111_1000 - 0111_1111

            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1000_0000 - 1000_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1000_1000 - 1000_1111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1001_0000 - 1001_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1001_1000 - 1001_1111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1010_0000 - 1010_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1010_1000 - 1010_1111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1011_0000 - 1011_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1011_1000 - 1011_1111

            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1100_0000 - 1100_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1100_1000 - 1100_1111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1101_0000 - 1101_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1101_1000 - 1101_1111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1110_0000 - 1110_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1110_1000 - 1110_1111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1111_0000 - 1111_0111
            7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, // 1111_1000 - 1111_1111
        };

    int byte;
    int byte_cnt;

    for (byte_cnt = 3; byte_cnt >= 0; byte_cnt--)
    {
        byte = (x >> (byte_cnt * 8)) & 0xff;
        if (byte != 0)
        {
            return msb_lut[byte] + (byte_cnt * 8);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: fastest to execute, but not to type ;)

Comment: erickson's answer is faster... It uses less memory, so it's more cache efficient.

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be solved with existing library calls.

```
int highestBit(int v){
  return fls(v) << 1;
}
```

The Linux man page gives more details on this function and its counterparts for other input types.

Comment: Actually, ffs returns the lowest order bit.

Comment: @Soren even better, use (8*sizeof(long long) - __builtin_clzll(v))

Comment: @Ragnar, if you going that way use `(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(long long) - __builtin_clzll(v)` but I don't this this formulation is sufficiently portable to need that. `<limits.h>`

Comment: Isn't this backwards?  Should be `1UL << fls(v)`.

Comment: No man page for this on Ubuntu 20.04 and it doesn't seem to be in glibc.  It's a FreeBSD invention as best I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need a portable solution and your code is executing on an x86 compatible CPU you can use _BitScanReverse() intrinsic function provided by Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler. It maps to BSR CPU instruction which returns the highest bit set.

Answer (score 3):

The best algorithm I like very much is:

```
unsigned hibit(unsigned n) {
    n |= (n >>  1u);
    n |= (n >>  2u);
    n |= (n >>  4u);
    n |= (n >>  8u);
    n |= (n >> 16u);
    return n - (n >> 1);
}
```

And it's easily extended for  uint64_t like that:

```
uint64_t hibit(uint64_t n) {
    n |= (n >>  1u);
    n |= (n >>  2u);
    n |= (n >>  4u);
    n |= (n >>  8u);
    n |= (n >> 16u);
    n |= (n >> 32u);
    return n - (n >> 1);
}
```

or even to __int128

```
__int128 hibit(__int128 n) {
    n |= (n >>  1u);
    n |= (n >>  2u);
    n |= (n >>  4u);
    n |= (n >>  8u);
    n |= (n >> 16u);
    n |= (n >> 32u);
    n |= (n >> 64u);
    return n - (n >> 1);
}
```

In addition is crossplatphorm solution independend of using compilator

Answer (score 2):

```
// Note doesn't cover the case of 0 (0 returns 1)
inline unsigned int hibit( unsigned int x )
{
  unsigned int log2Val = 0 ;
  while( x>>=1 ) log2Val++;  // eg x=63 (111111), log2Val=5
  return 1 << log2Val ; // finds 2^5=32
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nifty solution I came up with is to binary search the bits.

```
uint64_t highestBit(uint64_t a, uint64_t bit_min, uint64_t bit_max, uint16_t bit_shift){
    if(a == 0) return 0;
    if(bit_min >= bit_max){
        if((a & bit_min) != 0)
            return bit_min;
        return 0;
    }
    uint64_t bit_mid = bit_max >> bit_shift;
    bit_shift >>= 1;
    if((a >= bit_mid) && (a < (bit_mid << 1)))
        return bit_mid;
    else if(a > bit_mid)
        return highestBit(a, bit_mid, bit_max, bit_shift);
    else
        return highestBit(a, bit_min, bit_mid, bit_shift);

}
```

Bit max is the highest power of 2, so for a 64 bit number it would be 2^63. Bit shift should be initialized to half the number of bits, so for 64 bits, it would be 32.