# non-function operator based one-liner for magnitude of an int

Tags: language-agnostic

I was wondering if there is any way to get the magnitude of an *integer* without using function calls and only using operators (no control structures).

In case I'm using the term magnitude incorrectly here, what I mean is basically how many digits are occupied. eg. 2468 has a magnitude of 4.

Otherwise, what is the most efficient way to do this?
The best I could come up with is `while ( num /= 10 ) mag++;` but I'm just wondering if there's some sort of black magic out there I'm unaware of.

Solutions in a C style language are preferred (C, C++, Java, C#, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically you want ⌊log<sub>10</sub>(|x|)⌋ + 1. Unless x is 0.

The difference between operator and function that you give is rather arbitrary. One could always create a language with a ⌊log<sub>10</sub>(|x|)⌋ + 1 operator!

Still for the fun of it, we can start with creating an integeral log<sub>10</sub>(x) method, which is most easily done with simple comparison:

```
//assumes 32-bit int in max value. Add cases accordingly
return (x >= 1000000000) ? 9 : (x >= 100000000) ? 8 : (x >= 10000000) ? 7 : 
  (x >= 1000000) ? 6 : (x >= 100000) ? 5 : (x >= 10000) ? 4 : 
  (x >= 1000) ? 3 : (x >= 100) ? 2 : (x >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
```

We are going to add 1 to whatever result we get, so we don't even need that addition, we just change our result:

```
return (x >= 1000000000) ? 10 : (x >= 100000000) ? 9 : (x >= 10000000) ? 8 : 
  (x >= 1000000) ? 7 : (x >= 100000) ? 6 : (x >= 10000) ? 5 : 
  (x >= 1000) ? 4 : (x >= 100) ? 3 : (x >= 10) ? 2 : 1;
```

The bonus is that this also handles the case of x == 0 correctly.

Now we just need to abs it.

```
x = x > 0 ? x : -x;
return (x >= 1000000000) ? 10 : (x >= 100000000) ? 9 : (x >= 10000000) ? 8 : 
  (x >= 1000000) ? 7 : (x >= 100000) ? 6 : (x >= 10000) ? 5 : 
  (x >= 1000) ? 4 : (x >= 100) ? 3 : (x >= 10) ? 2 : 1;
```

And to one-liner it:

```
return ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 1000000000) ? 10 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 100000000) ? 9 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 10000000) ? 8 :  ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 1000000) ? 7 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 100000) ? 6 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 10000) ? 5 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 1000) ? 4 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 100) ? 3 : ((x > 0 ? x : -x) >= 10) ? 2 : 1;
```

The problem is whether you consider `?:` a control structure or not. It **is** an operator, but it does branch (and of more real impact than whether a control structure is used, though still a micro-opt to get rid of).

Non-branching should at least be possible in a multi-liner, lets see.

Non-branching abs is easy:

```
 (x ^ (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31); // assuming 32-bit int, adjust shift accordingly
```

Now for the logarithm, I cheat and look up some bit-twiddling hacks I can't remember. I'm just going to dry-code port this (since I've done C# so far and may as well stick with it) from what I can read at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html, and leave testing and fixing any bugs I've introduced as an exercise:

We start with finding log<sub>2</sub>(x);

```
int[] MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition = new int[]
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

int l = x >> 1; // first round down to one less than a power of 2 
l |= l >> 2;
l |= l >> 4;
l |= l >> 8;
l |= l >> 16;

l = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint)(l * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Now we can use this to find the base-10 logarithm:

```
int[] PowersOf10 = new int[]
    {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000,
     1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};

int t = (l + 1) * 1233 >> 12;
return t - (x < PowersOf10[t]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are constant-time "bit hacks" for computing related values, like [the highest bit that is set in a number.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161/find-the-highest-order-bit-in-c/53184#53184) This is analogous, because you want to find the highest digit that is non-zero.

However, since you are interested in the base-10 value, and these methods use binary arithmetic, I am not sure that they can be adapted. Looking at how they work might give you some ideas, though.

Comment: Indeed, I use the bitwise ops for base-2 stuff all the time, but this time I need to do some base-10, so it's got me scratching my noodle if there's anything similar.