# how to find left most 1 in a 32bit int in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitmask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the highest order bit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161/find-the-highest-order-bit-in-c)

How can I write a C function that will generate a mask indicating the leftmost `1` in `x`.

Ex: `0xFF00 -> 0x8000`, and `0x6600 -> 0x4000`. So far:

```
int left1(unsigned x){}
```

I understand, `0xFF00 == 1111 1111 0000 0000..`
and `0x6600 == 0110 0110 0000 0000..` but I'm stumped after that.

Comment: use bit shifting >> and masking &

Comment: If you cast it as signed, could you not do (x<0)?

Comment: How do you deal with endianess in this scenario? The left-most bit may not be the high bit

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Without any further elaboration, the implication is that "leftmost" means "most significant", since that's how we write numbers.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in two parts: first, use a technique called "bit smearing" to ensure that all the bits to the right of the first 1 are also 1:

```
x |= x >> 16;
x |= x >> 8;
x |= x >> 4;
x |= x >> 2;
x |= x >> 1;
```

At this point, an input of `0xFF00` will leave `x` equal to `0xFFFF`, and an input of `0x6600` will leave `x` equal to `0x7FFF`.  We can then leave just the highest `1` set using:

```
x ^= x >> 1;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first part be in the opposite order?

Comment: @alveko: It works just as well either way.

Comment: This does NOT work with negative numbers because the sign bit is sticky.

Comment: @don4of4: The question specifies `unsigned` as the type of the input number.

Answer (score 3):

Count the number of times it takes to bit-shift to the right until you reach 1, then bit-shift that 1 to the left by that same count.

```
int ct=0;
while (x > 1) { ct++; x = x >> 1; }
x = x << ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a bitmask, and then right-shift the value.

That is, create a bitmask so that your integer is '1000....' or '0.....' - depending on whether that first bit is a 0 or a 1.

Then take that integer and right-shift it until it becomes the least-significant-bit, rather than the most-significant. As an example, `0b10000000 >> 8` is 1.

So first, depending on the size of your integer, you have to shift, well, however many bits are relevant.

Then you have to create the bitmask. Let's just take a 1-byte integer:

`unsigned int i = 1 << 8` would create an integer i whose most significant bit is a 1.

Or you could use hex. You already know that `0xFF` == `11111111`. You can actually break it up further: `0xF0` == `11110000`

Since `0xF` == `1111` in binary, well, we will do the reverse. `1000` in binary is what, in hex? `1000` in binary is the number `8`, which also happens to equal `0x8`

So, for a single byte, the mask for the leftmost bit is `0x80`.

Now! Apply this to 32 bits!

Good luck!