# Set all bits up to given highest bit

Tags: bit-manipulation, twos-complement

If I have a binary number, say `x = 00010000`, I can set all bits up to the highest and only set bit by doing `y = x | (x - 1)` resulting in `y = 00011111`.

How can I achieve the same result if multiple bits are set, e.g. `x = 00010101`?

Comment: The task is equivalent to finding the highest set bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161/find-the-highest-order-bit-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589096/find-most-significant-bit-left-most-that-is-set-in-a-bit-array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [find first set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)

No possible solution with only bitwise operations.
If you want to code it the usual way, think "binary search" for more efficient algorithms.

Here's something to get you started but I am sure there are more efficient algos out there

```
int findfirstset(unsigned int x) {
    x |= (x >>  1);
    x |= (x >>  2);
    x |= (x >>  4);
    x |= (x >>  8);
    x |= (x >> 16);
    return x - (x >> 1);
}
```

From there you could do your operation:

```
y = x | (x - 1)
```

Comment: Why bother with `x - (x >> 1)` and `y = x | (x - 1)`? After `x |= (x >> 16);` you already have the result desired by OP.