# Finding dynamic bit mask

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitmask

I want to find a bit mask with only first bit set to 1 but mask length has to be determined dynamically taking in consideration number **n**.

For example if **n = 161**
161 in binary format is 10100001
Determined mask should be 10000000

So it can be compared like this:

10100001
10000000

Second example, **n = 34**
34 in binary format is 100010
Determined mask should be 100000
So it can be compared like this:

100010
100000

There is certainly mathematical solution to this and maybe even purely by moving bits around but I can't find solution in any of the two ways, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: No language tag? There are fairly general ways, but for example Java has [Integer.highestOneBit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int))

Comment: Solution should be mathematical or by moving bits which is language agnostic. I'm not looking for some X language obscure feature which has this implemented. I want to know process of getting there by myself.

Comment: So like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184/555045)?

Comment: @harold yes, accepted answer works, indeed clever solution but maybe (probably is) more efficient way than shifting bit by 1 to the right in the n and by 1 to the left in the mask in the same loop?

Comment: Yes, I linked to the second answer intentionally, the accepted one is just the naive way to do it while the second one is a log-step trick in general (for broadword computation).

Comment: That is it. Log step trick is just an answer I was looking for. Thanks.