# Bitwise - get position of first bit in a byte

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to think of an efficient algorithm that can return a bitmask giving the position of the first bit that is a '1', counted left from the input.

**For example:** 
000**1**0101 should give 000**1**0000 and
**1**1111111 should give **1**0000000

The obvious way I guess would be to do make a loop that checks first bit and shifts bitwise until end of string, but I would like to avoid loops if at all possible.

Anyone who thinks they have a good solution to this, feel free to post!

Comment: what language?  this might be a good one to post over on codegolf as a challenge :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the highest order bit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161/find-the-highest-order-bit-in-c)

Comment: it's just `1 << (31 - __builtin_clz(val))` for 32-bit int

Answer (score 1):

The function/OpCode you are looking for has a name: [`TZCNT`: "Count the Number of Trailing Zero Bits"](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TZCNT.html). It is available if your CPU supports the `BMI1` instruction set extension. 
In combination with [`BTS`: "Bit Test and Set"](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BTS.html) you can achieve your goal with two main OpCodes:

```
xor   eax, eax                ; Clears EAX and breaks dependencies
tzcnt edx, [memoryOperand]    ; Gets the count of trailing 0's in EDX
bts   eax, edx                ; Sets the bit found by TZCNT in EAX
```

The bit-space in this example is from `0..31`.